# How do I modify my .bst to accomodate both "and" and "\&" as bbl.and?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have used `makebst.tex` to generate a style to match AGPS v6 ([PDF Brief of style guide](https://www.library.uq.edu.au/_/sites/default/files/storage/webfile_read/files/referencing/agps_6.pdf)), however, I can't figure out how to get two styles of "and" for in-text citations. Using `\citet{}` I want to use `"and"`, but for `\citep{}` I want `"\&"`.

e.g.

`\citet{Smith2014}` : Smith and Adams (2014)

`\citep{Smith2014}` : (Smith & Adams 2014)

In my .bst file, I have created a new function `bbl.amp` to use `"\&"` in my reference list.

`FUNCTION {bbl.amp}
{ "\&"}`

However, it seems there is only one function called for in-text citations, `format.full.names`.

```
FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
 "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                }
                {
                  numnames #2 >
                    { "," * }
                    'skip$
                  if$
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

It is a bit beyond my skill to hack this. If I substitute `bbl.and` with my new `bbl.amp` then I will have the reverse issue and have `"\&"` throughout.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: I suspect one will have to (i) hack the bibtex function `bbl.and` to output a macro called, say, `\bbland` instead of a hard-coded conjunction (either "and" or "&") and (ii) hack the macros `\citet` and `\citep` so that they replace `\bbland` with either "and" (`\citet`) or "\&" (`\citep`). This assumes, of course, that you're working with a reasonably modern bibliography style which provides the function `bbl.and`; the basic `plain`, `unsrt`, `abbrv`, and `alpha` styles do no provide this feature. Fortunately, a style file created via the `makebst` utility provides the function `bbl.and`.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I'm hoping to keep the solution inside the `.bst` file. I'm thinking that the function `format.full.names` needs to either split in two, or some conditions added to the function so that it can use either `bbl.and` or my `bbl.amp`. Anyone with enough knowledge of BAFLL (BibTeX Anonymous Forth-Like Language -- Drew McDermott in comp.lang.lisp) ?

Comment: The `bst` does not know how the `\bibitem` are going to be called. Thus you have hack how the various `\citeX` commands operates.

Comment: Thanks @Guido, I'm now reading through your detailed solution and trying to get my head around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution is to define a new command to expand to `\&` or `and` depending  whether it is executed in a `\citep` or in a `\citep`.

To this end the first step is to define the `bbl.amp` function as follows:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.amp}
{ "\protect\myamp "}
```

This has the effect to insert `\protect\myamp` in the proper places in the `.bbl` file, in particular we need it in the optional argument of `\bibitem` which is used by `natbib` to print the citations.

The next step is to identify whether we are in a in a parenthetical citation (`\citep`). We can use the `etoolbox` package to create a toggle to indicate that we are in such a situation.

```
\newtoggle{myamp}
\preto{\citep}{\toggletrue{myamp}}
```

The second line above set the toggle `myamp` true when we enter in a parenthetical citation.

The final step is to provide the  definition of `\myamp`.

```
\newcommand{\myamp}{%
  \iftoggle{myamp}{\&\ }{and }%
  }
```

In the definition we use a conditional. The conditional determines whether the toggle `my amp` is true (thus we are in a parenthetical citation), then it instructs to print "&" or "and". Then we abuse the `\setcitestyle` to set the toggle to false.

```
\setcitestyle{open={[},close={]\global\togglefalse{myamp}}}
```

Here is a fulle MWE with some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Goossens1994LaTeX,
  author = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach},
  title = {The \LaTeX{} Companion, $2^{nd}$ Edition},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1994},
  url = {www.tex.stackexchange.com}
}
@book{Goossens1993LaTeX,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens},
  title = {The \LaTeX{} Companion, $2^{nd}$ Edition},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1993},
  url = {www.tex.stackexchange.com}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\newcommand{\myamp}{%
  \iftoggle{myamp}{\&\ }{and }%
  }

\setcitestyle{open={[},close={]\global\togglefalse{myamp}}}
\newtoggle{myamp}
\preto{\citep}{\toggletrue{myamp}}


\begin{document}

\verb|\citet|: \citet{Goossens1994LaTeX}

\verb|\citep|: \citep{Goossens1994LaTeX,Goossens1993LaTeX}

\verb|\citeauthor|: \citeauthor{Goossens1994LaTeX}

\verb|\citep|: \citep{Goossens1994LaTeX,Goossens1993LaTeX}

\verb|\cite|: \cite{Goossens1994LaTeX,Goossens1993LaTeX}

\verb|\citep*|: \citep*{Goossens1994LaTeX}

\verb|\citeauthor|: \citeauthor{Goossens1994LaTeX}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

and the output is:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! The only thing you (or the OP...) will need to change, I suspect, is to use `&` as the conjunction for the entries in the references. (I.e., "and" should only be used for `\citet`-like citations.

Comment: @Guido - Thank you for your comprehensive solution. Your MWE allowed me to incorporate into my document successfully and I have marked your answer as the solution.

Comment: @Mico - I have just edited the `.bst` file to force the reference list to use `&`.